# .htaccess and php redirect causing loop

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hey I searched all of the related questions and I didn't find any solution for my case.

**I have a script with urls like the following:**

```
htt://www.example.com/index.php/dosomthing/parametrs
```

**Now I used this:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in my default controller I check if the user is logged in or not, if not I redirect it to the login controller using this class function:

```
function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'location', $http_response_code = 302)
    {
        $uri = $this->config['home_url'] . ltrim($uri, '/');

        switch($method)
        {
            case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
                break;
            default         : header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
                break;
        }

        $this->dija = null;

        exit;
    }
```

It works on localhost but on the hosting it doesn't work and causes redirect loop, I'm really frustrated don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Change your RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

In the old case you're always rewriting to the same old url, and just prepending the index.php part once more, because there is no file that's named "index.php/"

Comment: thanks but didn't work also, this .htaccess I included in my question works in same host perfectly with app developed using laravel framework.. I think the problem is in php not htaccess but i dunno what I did wrong

Comment: I found out what was wrong, the problem wasn't neither in htacces nor php it was because $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] was empty because of server configuration, so the script kept redirecting to home controller..